# Python Tkinter table, content not showing

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a python tkinter code basically aimed to extract a multi-dimension list into a table. Below is what I have:

```
from Tkinter import *
def mainApp(Output):
    RRColor = '#%02x%02x%02x' % (0, 73,144);
    mGui = Tk();
    mGui.title('Relational Table');
    mGui.configure(background='grey')
    text = StringVar();
    title1 = Label(mGui, text = 'Premise', fg=RRColor, borderwidth=2).grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew", padx=1, pady=1)
    title2 = Label(mGui, text = 'Conclusion', fg=RRColor, borderwidth=2).grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew", padx=1, pady=1)
    title3 = Label(mGui, text = 'Support', fg=RRColor, borderwidth=2).grid(row=0, column=2, sticky="nsew", padx=1, pady=1)
    title4 = Label(mGui, text = 'Confidence', fg=RRColor, borderwidth=2).grid(row=0, column=3, sticky="nsew", padx=1, pady=1)
    title5 = Label(mGui, text = 'Lift', fg=RRColor, borderwidth=2).grid(row=0, column=4, sticky="nsew", padx=1, pady=1)
    for col in range(len(Output)):
        for row in range(len(Output[0])):
            text.set(Output[col][row])
            content = Label(mGui, textvariable=text, borderwidth=2, fg =RRColor, bg = 'white')
            content.grid(row=row+1, column=col, sticky='NSEW', padx=1, pady=1)
    mGui.mainloop();
```

I am calling this from somewhere else. I am wondering why the content is not showing on the grid. I have checked that the output is successfully passed over to this. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Your code has indentation errors, so it's impossible to know for certain what you intend for the code to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only using a single instance of `StringVar` that you are associating with every label being created in the loop. Each widget needs its own `StringVar`

("needs", as in "if you are using `StringVar`, you need to use a different one for each label", but strictly speaking, you don't need to use any `StringVar`s at all)